# How to set Custom View as Default View for SharePoint List?

Tags: list-view, view

I Have Created 2 Views for a List. Now I want to set Different views as the default view on different Logins.

I want to do this using c# code

**For Example:**

Views are as Following:

1. AllItems
2. UserView

Then

If Admin Logs in then List's Default View is AllItems

If User Logs in then List's Default View is UserView

How Can I do this using C# code?

Code Snippet:

```
                    SPUser LoggedInUser = web.CurrentUser;

                    SPList CurrentList = web.Lists[ListName];

                    if (LoggedInUser.LoginName == LoginUser)
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        CurrentList.Views[AllItems].DefaultView = false;
                        CurrentList.Views[UserView].DefaultView = true;
                        CurrentList.Update();              // Error here
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                    }
                    else if (LoggedInUser.LoginName == LoginAdmin)
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        CurrentList.Views[AllItems].DefaultView = true;
                        CurrentList.Views[UserView].DefaultView = false;
                        CurrentList.Update();               // Error here
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
```

Above Code is giving this error:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a
>   native frame is on top of the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is you're retrieving the view from an indexer. Try something like this for each view:

```
SPView allItemView = CurrentList.Views[AllItems];
allItemView.DefaultView = false;
allItemView.Update();
CurrentList.Update();
```

Additionally - this is database-heavy in terms of what you want to do (lots of read/writes just to set a default view depending on the user's group), I can't think at the minute of a better way of doing this but if there is, then try and find a way that limits the amount of data you need to get to/from the database. Think what impact this will have many when users are accessing the page at once.

Comment: An edit was suggested for this answer to put an Update statement for the parent list. I don't actually think this is required as the SPView's update statement should commit changes anyway. I do not have a VM to hand currently so I can't confirm this, however.

Comment: I also do not have a VM ready at hand. If anybody can confirm that there is no need of updating the parent list, I can revert the edit.

Comment: Its not Working Still  gives "Error: Access Denied"

Comment: Can you please explain more ....?